# How to query DBPedia data for a given Wikipedia URL?

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

If I want to query the RDF for [Appomattox Court House National Historical Park](http://dbpedia.org/page/Appomattox_Court_House_National_Historical_Park) in [DBPedia](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql), what's the query string if I search by wiki page URL?

I tested the following string but get no result:

```
select ?building 
where {
   ?building a dbo:Building .
   ?building foaf:primaryTopic <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appomattox_Court_House_National_Historical_Park>
} LIMIT 100
```

Comment: The URL `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appomattox_Court_House_National_Historical_Park` does not occur anywhere in the data about the Cooper Union building, and definitely not as the primary topic of it. I should also point that you are _probably_ using the `foaf:primaryTopic` relation the wrong way around - typically the DBPedia resource is the _object value_ of this relation, not the subject.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I used incorrect page, it should be http://dbpedia.org/page/Appomattox_Court_House_National_Historical_Park, can I change it back?  But the query return no data, is it correct?

Comment: you can edit your question to make the examples correct. Please do so, because at the moment it's not quite clear what exactly your  problem is.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra is right. if you use `foaf:primaryTopic` you have to reverse the triple pattern, or you use the property `foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in my comment as well: the problem is that you are using the `foaf:primaryTopic` relation the wrong way around. The wiki page is the *subject* of the relation, and the DBPedia resource the object value. So it should be this:

```
SELECT ?building 
WHERE {
    ?building a dbo:Building .
    <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appomattox_Court_House_National_Historical_Park> foaf:primaryTopic ?building .
} 
LIMIT 100
```

Alternatively, as @AKSW commented, you can use the inverse relation, which is called `foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf`:

```
SELECT ?building 
WHERE {
    ?building a dbo:Building .
    ?building foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appomattox_Court_House_National_Historical_Park> .
} 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Why is the `?building a dbo:Building .` pattern needed?  (I think it is not...)

Comment: @TallTed it was given in the question.