# why DBPedia query for given Wikipedia URLs works works only for some urls?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

I have a list of URLs to wikipedia pages and query dbpedia data on [lod.openlinksw.com](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql/) endpoint. The code is the same as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935461/how-to-query-dbpedia-data-for-a-given-wikipedia-url). 
What would be good to understand is: how is it possible that for some urls it doesn't work altough dbpedia pages have correct foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf urls?

Here a simplifyed query for the corresponding [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/page/Adi_Shankara) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara) pages.

```
   PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
   PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
   PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

   SELECT Distinct ?name ?s ?url WHERE {
   ?s a foaf:Person .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s  rdf:type  dbo:FictionalCharacter }.
   ?s foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url.
   ?s rdfs:label ?name.
   filter(langMatches(lang(?name), "en")).
   ?s foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara>.
   }
   LIMIT 1
```

From the list with ~40 urls that were pulled from wikipedia, i get ~10 empty responses. First i thought may be there is something wrong with the urls but most of them seem fine. Here more of 'not working' cases:

- used in query >> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_I_of_Norway,
  dbpedia.org/page/Harald_Fairhair >>
  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Fairhair
- used in query >> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivar_the_Boneless,
  dbpedia.org/page/Ivar_the_Boneless >>
  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivar_the_Boneless
- used in query >> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayarāśi_Bhaṭṭa,
  dbpedia.org/page/Jayarāśi_Bhaṭṭa >>
  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayarāśi_Bhaṭṭa
- used in query >> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_I_of_Scotland,
  dbpedia.org/page/Kenneth_MacAlpin >>
  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_MacAlpin
- used in query >> en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Deyu,
  dbpedia.org/page/Li_Deyu >>
  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Deyu

In 1st (Harald_Fairhair) and in 4th (Kenneth_MacAlpin) cases there are different urls that point to the same wikipage so i need to find out how to deal with such cases. But i don't understand why the rest doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, note that there's no guarantee that lod.openlinksw.com data is ever in sync with dbpedia.org  data ... nor that dbpedia.org data is in sync with en.wikipedia.org data (as this is usually 6-18 months delayed batch update) ... nor that live.dbpedia.org data is in sync with wikipedia.org data (though this is generally true within days if not minutes, it is sometimes within months).  Also note that `dbpedia.org/page/` URLs point to human-friendly pages about entities identified with `dbpedia.org/resource/` URIs.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled, you even added links to the corresponding DBpedia pages, but did you ever had a look at one of the pages to see what's going on? I mean, for example the entity of your query, `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Adi_Shankara`, did you check the `rdf:type` relation? It's obvious that there is no `foaf:Person` triple. And why not using `dbo:Person`?

Comment: Regarding the other thing. Wikipedia redirects is what you have to resolve in the SPARQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Revised Query based on Comment Thread

```
   PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
   PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
   PREFIX  rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

   SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?s ?url 
   WHERE {
     VALUES ?url { <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara> 
                   <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_I_of_Norway> 
                   <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivar_the_Boneless> 
                   <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayarāśi_Bhaṭṭa> 
                   <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_I_of_Scotland> 
                   <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Deyu> 
                 }

                       ?s ^dbo:wikiPageRedirects*
                          /foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf  ?url .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s  rdf:type               dbo:FictionalCharacter }
                       ?s  rdfs:label             ?name .
   FILTER(langMatches(LANG(?name), "en")).
   }
```

#### Original answer

How does [this query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=+++PREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A+++PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A+++PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A+++SELECT+Distinct+%3Fname+%3Fs+%3Furl+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++VALUES+%3Furl+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAdi_Shankara%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHarald_I_of_Norway%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FIvar_the_Boneless%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FJayar%C4%81%C5%9Bi_Bha%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADa%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FKenneth_I_of_Scotland%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLi_Deyu%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fs++foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf++%3Furl+.%0D%0A%23++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fs++rdf%3Atype+++++++++++++++foaf%3APerson+.%0D%0A+++FILTER+NOT+EXISTS+%7B+%3Fs++rdf%3Atype+++++++++++++++dbo%3AFictionalCharacter+%7D%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fs++rdfs%3Alabel+++++++++++++%3Fname+.%0D%0A+++FILTER%28langMatches%28LANG%28%3Fname%29%2C+%22en%22%29%29.%0D%0A%23++%3Fs+foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAdi_Shankara%3E.%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0A%23+++LIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) (and [live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=+++PREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A+++PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A+++PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A+++SELECT+Distinct+%3Fname+%3Fs+%3Furl+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++VALUES+%3Furl+%7B+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAdi_Shankara%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHarald_I_of_Norway%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FIvar_the_Boneless%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FJayar%C4%81%C5%9Bi_Bha%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADa%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FKenneth_I_of_Scotland%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLi_Deyu%3E+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fs++foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf++%3Furl+.%0D%0A%23++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fs++rdf%3Atype+++++++++++++++foaf%3APerson+.%0D%0A+++FILTER+NOT+EXISTS+%7B+%3Fs++rdf%3Atype+++++++++++++++dbo%3AFictionalCharacter+%7D%0D%0A+++++++++++++++++++++++%3Fs++rdfs%3Alabel+++++++++++++%3Fname+.%0D%0A+++FILTER%28langMatches%28LANG%28%3Fname%29%2C+%22en%22%29%29.%0D%0A%23++%3Fs+foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAdi_Shankara%3E.%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0A%23+++LIMIT+10&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) from DBpedia) work for you?

```
   PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
   PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
   PREFIX  rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

   SELECT Distinct ?name ?s ?url WHERE {
   VALUES ?url { <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara> 
                 <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_I_of_Norway> 
                 <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivar_the_Boneless> 
                 <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayarāśi_Bhaṭṭa> 
                 <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_I_of_Scotland> 
                 <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Deyu> 
               }

                       ?s  foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf  ?url .
#                      ?s  rdf:type               foaf:Person .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s  rdf:type               dbo:FictionalCharacter }
                       ?s  rdfs:label             ?name .
   FILTER(langMatches(LANG(?name), "en")).
#  ?s foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_Shankara>.
   }
#   LIMIT 10
```

Does any of that help you understand what was going wrong before?

Comment: oo i see!, the reason is - i am using foaf:Person instead of dbo:Person for the rdf:type property. And the reason why it worked for the most of the queries is that their rdf:type probably have both (e.g. dbpedia.org/page/Emperor_Xuānzong_of_Tang). I am a bit confused about fundementals. Firstly, how do i know which property will be used for sure? Second, why your query works even for the urls which are redirects (e.g. the Harald_Fairhair  who is Harald_I_of_Norway)?

Comment: @nika it works for redirects because he omits the `?s  rdf:type               foaf:Person .` triple pattern by using the `#` char in front of it. Remove the `#` and replace `foaf:Person` with `dbo:Person` and it will not return the result for `Harald_I_of_Norway`

Comment: it will work with `?s  ^dbo:wikiPageRedirects*/foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf  ?url .`

Comment: ok i run a script with dbo:Person and now i am loosing less and different pages. If in your query there is a statement ?s  rdf:type  dbo:Person. than "Kenneth I of Scotland" and "Harald I of Norway" are lost despite the fact that they do have dbo:Person. The only difference that i notice is that not found pages have both properties: dbo:Person and foaf:Person but why should it cause any problem?

Comment: @AKSW i think i am probably missing some basics, are you saying that there is some 'hidden' entry type (mechanism) for redirects and because of that all properties that belong to the original url do not apply? That would explain the behaviour..the lost pages have different urls indeed. thanks. I need to look up the syntax for your suggestion to understand it fully. So query tries to find pages with specified foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf and if nothing is found it looks in the dbo:wikiPageRedirects. If the latter works it gives the dbpedia page but not if the rdf:type is specified?

Comment: @nika no, you were asking why the query works with `Harald_I_of_Norway` although it's clearly a redirect to some other resource in DBpedia. I said, it's because the triple pattern `?s rdf:type dbo:Person` is ignored totally - look at the query, there is a `#` in front of the triple pattern.

Comment: @nika And I already told you that `Harald I of Norway` is a redirect to another entry, so where do you see that it belongs to the class `dbo:Person`? In the browser you'll just see the resource it redirects to. Did you read my comment with `?s ^dbo:wikiPageRedirects*/foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url .` which you should use?

Comment: @AKSW when i wrote the 1st comment i didn't see yours because of the browser. Only after posting i saw your explanations and replayed to them. I looked up the property path syntax and your query works and more importantly it makes sense now. Basicly, two independent misconceptions..  i assumed the foaf:Person property exists for all persons and didn't know that dbpedia uses redirects too. So when i looked at dbpedia pages from the query results i didn't think that some of them are not the actual results but dbpedia redirects. Thanks for help.

Comment: @AKSW your `?s ^dbo:wikiPageRedirects*/foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url .` is a essential to my question but i don't know how do i indicate it here.

Comment: @nika what is not clear with `?s ^dbo:wikiPageRedirects*/foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url .`? you can use it instead of `?s foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url .` - you should get more results or not?

Comment: @AKSW, gosh i meant i don't know how to make it clear on stackoverflow. Your query works, skript finds all pages! :).

Comment: @nika You could edit the answer of TallTed and he has to approve it I guess if he's fine with it